# Максимальный объем обучающих данных

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Вопрос по scikit-learn: какой максимальный объем обучающих данных может обработать эта библиотека? Если я правильно понимаю, то данные для обработки сначала загружаются в ОЗУ. Может ли эта библиотека обработать объем данных в 10 Гб (разом или частями), если оперативка позволяет загружать намного больше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудно дать однозначный ответ на этот слишком общий вопрос.

Практически все **известные мне** методы и функции в `sklearn` могут работать с данными только в памяти. Причем многие методы создают дополнительные копии данных (или части данных) в памяти.

Но некоторые методы (например [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer), [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)) возвращают сжатые матрицы `sparsed matrix`, которые занимают намного меньше места в памяти (все нулевые значения, которых обычно 90+% - практически не занимают места в памяти) - это здОрово экономит память.

В общем у вас для одних и тех же данных могут возникнуть или не возникнуть проблемы с нехваткой памяти, в зависимости от того что вы делаете и как вы это делаете...

Comment: Жаль, что у меня нет пока системных знаний по этому поводу. Из того, что я понял, читая статьи в scikit-learn, некоторые классификаторы поддерживают функции частичного обучения partial_fit. На сайте этой библиотеки есть [статья](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html), посвященная обработке объемов данных, не помещающихся в ОЗУ. Кроме того, есть пример использования partial_fit. Пока разбираюсь.

Comment: @GlassedMichail,  спасибо за ссылку! Я теперь тоже буду разбираться с [этим шикарным примером](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-out-of-core-classification-py)